# How to download complete dataset through OAPIF using ogr2ogr?

Tags: ogr2ogr, ogc-api, ogc-api-features, finland

The [National Land Survey of Finland](https://www.maanmittauslaitos.fi/en) provides data on cadastral parcels using the [OGC API - Features](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/oapif.html) system. To list the available datasets, I do:

```
KEY=example-api-key
URL=avoin-paikkatieto.maanmittauslaitos.fi/kiinteisto-avoin/simple-features/v3/
ogrinfo OAPIF:https://${KEY}:@${URL}
```

(You can get your own `KEY` [here](https://omatili.maanmittauslaitos.fi/).) The response I get:

```
INFO: Open of `OAPIF:https://bed893ad-c8b1-46d5-bbec-6af5742cc2cc:@avoin-paikkatieto.maanmittauslaitos.fi/kiinteisto-avoin/simple-features/v3/'
      using driver `OAPIF' successful.
1: ProjisoidunPalstanSijaintitiedot (title: Projisoidun palstan sijaintitiedot) (Polygon)
2: KiinteistotunnuksenSijaintitiedot (title: Kiinteistötunnuksen sijaintitiedot) (Point)
3: MaaraalanOsanSijaintitiedot (title: Määräalan osan sijaintitiedot) (Point)
4: KiinteistorajanSijaintitiedot (title: Kiinteistörajan sijaintitiedot) (Line String)
5: PalstanSijaintitiedot (title: Palstan sijaintitiedot) (Polygon)
6: RajamerkinSijaintitiedot (title: Rajamerkin sijaintitiedot) (Point)
7: ProjisoidunPalstanKiinteistotunnuksenSijaintitiedot (title: Projisoidun palstan kiinteistötunnuksen sijaintitiedot) (Point)
```

I believe the cadastral parcel dataset is the 5th one, ie *PalstanSijaintitiedot*. To download it, I execute:

```
ogr2ogr output.geojson OAPIF:https://${KEY}:@${URL} PalstanSijaintitiedot
```

GeoJSON generation starts immediately. I can observe how the number of features grow within `output.geojson`. Based on the rate of growth, I expected this download to take at least a few hours.

And indeed, a few hours later I have `output.geojson`, the above `ogr2ogr` command executed without raising an error. However, I got suspicious that the dataset I downloaded is not complete, as the geometries it contained had big gaps in them, and not all of Finland was covered. I repeated the above quoted `ogr2ogr` command, but then the file I got had vastly different number of features than the file downloaded a few hours before that (~1.3 million vs ~3 million - both numbers are less than the number of cadastral parcels in Finland).

In both cases, the command seemed to have executed successfully, without raising an error. The produced GeoJSONs were also fine.

**How can I make sure I download the entire dataset via the OAPIF endpoint?**

If I knew how to raise an error when the result is incomplete, I would be closer to a solution: then I could reinitiate download everytime I get an incomplete dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few hints:

- As documented in  https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/oapif.html#open-options, the default page size is only 10. If you expect to get 4 million parcels, then GDAL needs to make 400000 requests. That should work just fine, but it would be better to use as big page size as the server supports. Try for example with `-oo PAGE_SIZE=10000`
- As an alternative to including the KEY in the server address it is possible to send the KEY by using the open option USERPWD. A third option is to use the configuration option GDAL_HTTP_USERPWD https://gdal.org/user/configoptions.html. All the options do the same thing finally so they are all as good.
- GeoJSON is not an optimal format for big datasets like this. GeoJSON does not support spatial indexes and it means that using your 4 million feature GeoJSON file with QGIS will be slow. I recommend using GeoPackage instead. GDAL creates spatial index for gpkg by default. If the parcel data includes also meaningful parcel IDs then you can create an index on the id field afterwards.
- If you just want to get the data for the whole country, it seems that you can download all the parcels in GeoPackage or GeoJSON format also from this download service https://asiointi.maanmittauslaitos.fi/karttapaikka/tiedostopalvelu/kiinteistorekisterikartta_vektori?lang=en
- I am not sure what happens if the GDAL OAPIF driver does not get some page properly. Does it fail and close, or does it continue with the next page. By adding `--debug on` into your command you would get debugging info that should show possible errors. Unfortunately it will print very much data in any case and finding the errors may by difficult.